# Considerations for using auto generated proxies for web services (Advantages and Disadvantages)

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, auto-generate

We are using a lot of manual code in .net (through HttpWebRequest) to access some web services. I was reading we do not need to do this as we can easily generate proxies. Has anyone converted from manual to auto-generated services. We do need to use some customized settings like UseProxyServer based on config settings and client certificates.

What are the considerations I need to take care of? Any helpful link is really appreciated.

**Update (as pointed by John Saunders):** Our web services are using WS-Security and hence the need to pass UsernameToken.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? And are you still using the old "Add Web Reference"?

Comment: We have .net 4.0 available to us. Web Services are exposed to us through SOAP and WSDL. I created Proxy code by "Add Service Reference" through VS 2010 (Is that not how you generate proxies?)

Comment: it is the correct way. There was an older way to do it, and some still use it; that's what I was trying to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you would have set "manually" can be set on the proxy class. You should use the proxy unless you have a specific reason not to. It will save you a great deal of time that you could spend solving other problems.

Comment: Thanks John, but one issue which I have become aware is related with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886987/web-service-request-authentication I think we need to use MessageInspector to modify header to pass UsernameToken

Comment: Please update your question to indicate that you are using WS-Security. That makes a huge difference. Also, if the WSDL of the service properly describes its authentication requirements, then you will probably _not_ need to use `MessageInspector`. WS-Security and `UsernameToken` is  a standard security scenario - you do not need to create a custom `MessageInspector` for that.